# Remove space around uppercase header

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a title which is displayed in uppercase letters. I would like to have just 2 pixels between this title and the framed box below.

If the text contains lowercase letters like ’g’, there is no space below, but once all ’g’, ’y’ and ’j’ letters are gone, it appears.

Is there any cross-browser method of getting rid of that space? Apparently browsers display different amount of empty space:   https://jsfiddle.net/5o94va6p/13/, so tricks like `line-height: 0.7` work in Firefox but eat too much space in Safari.

Comment: You write: "If the text is normal" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the text to make this explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Safari and chrome look similar in terms of empty space. The browser that looks different is Firefox. I would only specify line height for it using CSS. This way, Firefox will look good, and it will not effect the look in other browsers.

Try this code which will target only Firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h1 {
       line-height: 0.7
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work if Firefox will render it one way and all other browsers the other way. I am afraid that each browser is doing its own calculation and there will be some differences.

Comment: @Michal in my test on Mac, Chrome and Safari looked exactly the same in terms of empty space. The only browser that rendered different space is Firefox. As for Internet Explorer, I didn't test it, and frankly, I don't think anyone is using it anymore.

Comment: Alas, Chrome/Windows gives more space than Safari/macOS, so it seems it may be also OS-dependent.

Comment: @Michal Yeah, that's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

try using this -

```
.box{
  margin-top: 2px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: It makes the space in Firefox even bigger.

Answer (score 0):

The space below the baseline which is needed for letter like y, g, p etc. is ALWAYS there, it's part of the line-height - this is the reason for your problem. You can't change that unless you define a negative margin-bottom value, like

```
.my_heading {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The problem is that the space is different for Firefox and other browsers - see my example. Adding fixed negative margin does not solve that, the space will be still big for FF, small for Safari.

Comment: Is the exact same font used? You could try to add a definition for line-height in pixels. The default line-height might differ between Browsers.

Comment: That’s the problem, the same font needs different spacing in different browsers.

Comment: But If you define the line-height in pixels?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, if you have font-size: 36px, then line-height: 1.0 and line-height: 36px should work the same.